# HTML Printing using Gecko or Webkit engine

Tags: html, printing, webkit, gecko

Is there a way where I can directly print html file or url without invoking any dialogs in .NET?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Try this program: http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/. It will allow you to generate an image (or pdf) of a web page. Once you have that there are a variety of ways to print it. For example: [Print existing PDF (or other files) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273675/print-existing-pdf-or-other-files-in-c).