# How to print a document using PrintDialog in C#

Tags: c#, printing

Here is my sample code:

```
printDocument1.DocumentName = "C:\a.pbf";// PrintDocument printDocument1
printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
printDialog1.AllowPrintToFile = true;
printDialog1.AllowSelection = true;
printDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;
printDialog1.PrintToFile = true;
if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    printDocument1.Print();
```

It runs, but it's printing an empty page. What's wrong with this?

Comment: what is type is printDocument1 ?

Comment: @ABKolan - I think we can assume it is a [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx)

Comment: Hey mate, I know it has been a long time since this questioned was opened, but you need to accept the answer :) - good question though!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print Pdf in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566186/print-pdf-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 7):

You need to handle the [`PrintPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage.aspx) event to actually provide the contents; MSDN has a [full example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx). The [`DocumentName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.documentname.aspx) is purely something to show to the user - it is *not* the path of an existing file to magically print.

For printing an existing PDF, maybe look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273675/print-existing-pdf-or-other-files-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

do this :

```
public static void PrintToASpecificPrinter()
        {     
                using (PrintDialog printDialog=new PrintDialog ())
                {
                printDialog.AllowSomePages = true;
                printDialog.AllowSelection = true;
                if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    var StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                    StartInfo.Verb = "printTo";
                    StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName + "\"";
                    StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    StartInfo.FileName = fileName;

                    Process.Start(StartInfo);
                }
                    
                }
                

        }
```