# Print automatically after PDF is generated in c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm developing a billing application, in that project I need to generate a PDF, for that I use 'iTextSharp.dll' to generate pdf. It works fine. After PDF generation, I need to print that PDF file automatically without any action. My PDF generation code as follow:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("d:\\Bill1.pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
document.Add(table1);
document.close();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167995/generate-a-pdf-that-automatically-prints?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216517/print-created-pdf-automatically-after-creation?rq=1

Comment: @HanletEscaño How is a `PrintDialog` without any action?

Comment: after displaying pdf immediately the print action execute