# C# print pdf file in wpf application programatically

Tags: wpf, pdf

I have a WPF application and I want to be able to print PDF document, but I don't want use the Adobe Reader (because I don't know if on client machine adobe was installed). Is there another way to print pdf in different manner programmatically in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use cmd command to print, so in your program use exec... more info [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a955f724-653b-4dbd-a51d-989e67169b16/ms-library-for-pdf-print-for-a-c-window-without-any-driver)

or then [here in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566186/print-pdf-in-c-sharp)