# Print a file(PDf) by using PrintDialog in C#

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, printdialog

Hello everybody this is my code that I try get a file with Open File Dialog And print the file
 But its printing an Empty page :( :(

### please help me :)

```
   private void tsmprint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
            {
                PrintDocument Pd = new PrintDocument();

                Pd.DocumentName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                 printDialog1.Document = Pd;
                if (printDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Pd.Print();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566186/print-pdf-in-c-sharp You cannot directly print PDF using PrintDocument. Use PDF Viewer or third party library.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use external library, with the following msdn [example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Print-PDF-file-in-C-5b6e66b7) you can print the PDF files with the default printer or any other network connected printer as well as select the pages you want to print:

```
        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(); 
        doc.LoadFromFile(FilePathandFileName); 

        //Use the default printer to print all the pages 
        //doc.PrintDocument.Print(); 

        //Set the printer and select the pages you want to print 

        PrintDialog dialogPrint = new PrintDialog(); 
        dialogPrint.AllowPrintToFile = true; 
        dialogPrint.AllowSomePages = true; 
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.MinimumPage = 1; 
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.MaximumPage = doc.Pages.Count; 
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1; 
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.ToPage = doc.Pages.Count; 

        if (dialogPrint.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
        { 
            //Set the pagenumber which you choose as the start page to print 
            doc.PrintFromPage = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.FromPage; 
            //Set the pagenumber which you choose as the final page to print 
            doc.PrintToPage = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.ToPage; 
            //Set the name of the printer which is to print the PDF 
            doc.PrinterName = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.PrinterName; 

            PrintDocument printDoc = doc.PrintDocument; 
            dialogPrint.Document = printDoc; 
            printDoc.Print(); 
        }
```

Comment: Will this work only for printing pdfs? Is there a more generic way?

Comment: Which external library you're using? the link was dead already...

Comment: Where is this "PDF Document" class from?

Answer (score -1):

PrintDocument won't print a PDF by itself.  Try [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5566234/3407841) which explains how to use whatever application is associated with PDF files and the 'print' verb.