# 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform

Tags: c#, printing, process

I want to print a PDF file from C# code without user interaction.

I tried [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5566234/1563833) but it is not working for me.

This is the code I tried:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
     CreateNoWindow = true,
     Verb = "print",
     FileName = @"G:\Visual Studio Projects\PrintWithoutGUI\PrintWithoutGUI\Courses.pdf" //put the correct path here
};
p.Start();
```

I get this **exception :**

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'`

Comment: Try setting `UseShellExecute` to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the correct way to write your code

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Verb = "print",
    FileName = "PDfReader.exe", //put the path to the pdf reading software e.g. Adobe Acrobat
    Arguments = "PdfFile.pdf" // put the path of the pdf file you want to print
};
p.Start();
```

Comment: is there away to not open the **.exe** application ?

Comment: nope, this is the only way to do this. unless you used a pdf library in your project. and there are many of them. for example you can use **IronPDF**, but it's not free.
other than this i think this is the only choice you have.
plus, in most cases the **.exe** that will run will not be visible, because you've set the *CreateNoWindow* property to true

Comment: i asked you because the **.exe** application appeared !
thanks

Comment: you can try adding `WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,` to the initialization of your `new ProcessStartInfo()`

Comment: you can also try to set the `WindowStyle` to `ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized` if the above didn't work

Comment: i did what you suggested for me and the **.exe** application [adobe reader] still being visible , however ,i used Spre.pdf library to do the hide work 
thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

try this by add     **UseShellExecute=true** it will print to default printer but if you want to print to a specific print change the **verb** print to verb printTo by spefiying the name of the printer **Arguments** proprety.

```
 private static void PrintByProcess()
    {
        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute=true,
                Verb = "print",
                FileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\doc.pdf"
            };

            p.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Yes, changes in .NET Core require us to use `UseShellExecute` now. See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/17938