# Latency printing from application to networkprinter

Tags: c#, printing, process

I am trying print pdf file from application to network printer it will take more than 7 minutes but the pdf file sent immediately to the printer queue and i also try to one manual print in the same server open the adobe and give one test print the document is printed with 2 minutes.not able to find why the latency is there?

```
private static async Task PrintPDFfilemethod(string strPath)
{
       try 
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    
        {
                Verb = "printto",
                FileName = printfilenamewithpath,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        };
        processStartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + printername + "\"";
        Process process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = processStartInfo
        };
        process.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
        process.WaitForInputIdle();
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
        if (!process.CloseMainWindow())
            process.Kill();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `"printto"`? I guess the handler of this verb is printing differently than adobe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print Pdf in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566186/print-pdf-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Hi @k j /t can you give some exmple?