# Faster method for printing PDF files in C#

Tags: c#, printing

I currently have a C# console application that prints PDF documents.
My problem is that it take a lot of time for the pdf to get spooled and eventually printed.
Even when I set the printer driver to Direct Printing it still takes some time.

I am looking for ways to speed up the printing process. I would appreciate any suggestions.
I will be willing to look at Free or inexpensive nuget packages. Or any Silent methods of printing.
I have tried using the adobe dll but that opens up a window, which I am trying to avoid.

I am using the code below to print the PDF

```
            var printer = _appConfiguration.GetValue<string>("PRINTERS:RDLReceipt1");
            var filename = @"C:\\TEMP\\reciept-" + barcode + ".pdf";
            var nopages = 0;
            using (var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(filename))
            {
                nopages = pdfDocument.PageCount;
                using (var printDocument = pdfDocument.GetPrintDocument())
                {
                    printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;
                    printDocument.Print();
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the size of the file and how many pages are there? Do you print on a local or remote device? What operating system and version? What machine processor and ram? What technology do you use to print i.e. PdfDocument comes from what library? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566186/print-pdf-in-c-sharp

Comment: The PDF's Range from 40kb - 600kb. 1 - 30 pages. I print to a remote thermal printer.
The software runs on windows server 2019 standard, with 20 gb of RAM and 8 CPU's. PDFDocument is a IronPDF method. A third part nuget package.

Comment: Remote adds delay... How many MHz CPU? I forgot to ask: does the PDF have a lot of images? How about printing with Acrobat, Word or a browser?

Comment: The pdfs are just text. When I print to the printer from acrobat on the printer server it prints immediately. CPU is 2.3 GHZ. A very serious machine. I have gone through the thread you sent me before and have tried most of those packages none of them worked for me.

Comment: Have you tried using another .NET library? https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package?q=pdf+print

Comment: Yes I looked at all of those and they average $700.

Comment: Indeed... No open-source or more affordable in the list? What about that? https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+github+print+pdf

Comment: Thanks will give it a try

Comment: You may check Spire.PDF: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Print/How-to-print-PDF-document-in-C.html