# Printing sharepoint list libraries using Silver light and C sharp

Tags: sharepoint, printing

I am trying to print the files in the sharepoint document libraries. Can any one help me to print the files without opening the files.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the solution provided in following post it is given for pdf but should work for others as well 
[Print existing PDF (or other files) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273675/print-existing-pdf-or-other-files-in-c)