# Open PDF and print to PDF programmatically C#

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

I am developing an application that is able to open and display PDFs after I open them and print them to another PDF using CutePDF, but the originals are not viewable.

I am looking for a way to programmatically open a PDF file, and print to another PDF file (not necessarily using CutePDF, just printing to another PDF is the desired functionality).

This will be integrated into a C# .NET project.  Are there any suggestions how to go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print existing PDF (or other files) in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273675/print-existing-pdf-or-other-files-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Office Interop and generate the PDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412305%28v=office.12%29.aspx), when you say "print to another pdf", I imagine you mean just generate? Or are you saying spool them to a pdf print driver that essentially will just create a  PDF to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Use [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/), which is available in Java and C# versions. I have used the Java version successfully. I recommend the *iText in Action* book to help you get up to speed with iText faster. The book discusses only the Java API, but I imagine you will be able to learn the principles of iText from the book and then figure out the minor differences for the C# version.

Answer (score -1):

To implement this you can use [PDFFlow](https://go.pdfflow.io/pdfflow) library for generating PDF files from C#. It has easy fluent syntax and many features.
Here are many examples of real complex PDF documents: [examples](https://go.pdfflow.io/pdfdocs)
Good luck :)