# How to print speedily through a .NET WPF Windows Application?

Tags: .net, wpf, printing

I currently have a .NET 4.0 WPF application that prints labels using a pdf and adobe reader as the middleman-- it creates a PDF with the desired content and opens/prints/closes on reader.

My question is how to print to the printer directly through the application. I'd like to know if the following options exist:

1. Print directly to the printer classicly (really hope someone knows how to do this)-- as in using the fonts built in to the printer. Its an old dot matrix printer, and i imagine it would look better and run faster than the anti-aliased pdfs do. The anti-aliased isnt looking so great, i have to make the font bold for it to be readable and thats an ink issue. I've tried every font, too.
2. Print through WPF some other way. In this case i would need to know what thats like in terms of speed and quality and functionality.

Something you should know-- it will need to print foreign characters like é and such.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566186/print-pdf-in-c) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463165/open-pdf-and-print-to-pdf-programmatically-c) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273675/print-existing-pdf-or-other-files-in-c) printing of pdf can usually only be accomplished through some 3rd party library.

As you say you are creating the pdfs yourself, if it is an option, I would recommend creating XPS files instead. For them .Net has built in support and you can print them however you want.

The antialiased fonts is another question - which I'm sorry to not be able to answer.