# Sending data to USB printer in C#?

Tags: c#, zebra-printers

I have script code for zebra TLP2844 printer in a text file. I need to print that script file to a printer connected via USB.  I executed that script using parallel port by using DOS command:

```
/c type filename.txt >PRN
```

But the printer is coonnected to USB. How to send printing commands to usb? Should I use the printdocument class?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Microsoft has this sample code available to use:

[How to send raw data to a printer by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class RawPrinterHelper
{
  // Structure and API declarions:
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
  public class DOCINFOA
  {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDocName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pOutputFile;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDataType;
  }
  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="OpenPrinterA", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="ClosePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern bool StartDocPrinter( IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level,  [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="EndDocPrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="StartPagePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="EndPagePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="WritePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten );

  // SendBytesToPrinter()
  // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
  // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
  // Returns true on success, false on failure.
  public static bool SendBytesToPrinter( string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
  {
    Int32    dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
    IntPtr    hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
    DOCINFOA    di = new DOCINFOA();
    bool    bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.
    di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
    di.pDataType = "RAW";

    // Open the printer.
    if( OpenPrinter( szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero ) )
    {
      // Start a document.
      if( StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di) )
      {
        // Start a page.
        if( StartPagePrinter(hPrinter) )
        {
          // Write your bytes.
          bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
          EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
      }
      ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    }
    // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
    // about why not.
    if( bSuccess == false )
    {
      dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    }
    return bSuccess;
  }

  public static bool SendFileToPrinter( string szPrinterName, string szFileName )
  {
    // Open the file.
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
    // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
    Byte []bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
    bool bSuccess = false;
    // Your unmanaged pointer.
    IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
    int nLength;

    nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
    // Read the contents of the file into the array.
    bytes = br.ReadBytes( nLength );
    // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
    pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
    // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
    // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
    bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
    // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
    return bSuccess;
  }

  public static bool SendStringToPrinter( string szPrinterName, string szString )
  {
    IntPtr pBytes;
    Int32 dwCount;

    // How many characters are in the string?
    // Fix from Nicholas Piasecki:
    // dwCount = szString.Length;
    dwCount = (szString.Length + 1) * Marshal.SystemMaxDBCSCharSize;

    // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
    // the string to ANSI text.
    pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
    // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
    SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Includes bug fix from [Nicholas Piasecki](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/03/sending-raw-epl2-directly-to-a-zebra-lp2844-via-c/)

Comment: Works perfectly. Just copy-paste-"call SendStringToPrinter".
Except: using System.IO; is missing. Add this too.

Comment: I tried this for printing a PDF file, the WritePrinter function returns true, I see my document in the printing list, but nothing is printed. (If  print the same file outside the code everything works, so the printer is ready)

Comment: This won't work with PDF.  See [Print existing PDF (or other files) in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/273729/719186)

Comment: @Esmigol I don't see why not.  If it doesn't work, document your issue into a new question and reference this question and answer.

Comment: The FileStream and BinaryReader need disposing

Answer (score 2):

You can also do a share/capture of the printer as LPT and then you can print via the type command.

http://www.nrgsoft.com/support/activekb/questions.php?questionid=11

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me!

```
 public partial class USB : Form
{
    public USB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDataType;
    }
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.
        di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;

        // How many characters are in the string?
        // Fix from Nicholas Piasecki:
        // dwCount = szString.Length;
        dwCount = (szString.Length + 1) * Marshal.SystemMaxDBCSCharSize;

        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }     


    private void buttonSEND_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog open = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        string dados = "";
        if (open.ShowDialog().Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(open.FileName);
            dados = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
        string printer = "PRINTER NAME";

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            SendStringToPrinter(printer, dados);    
        }

    }
}
```