# USB Receipt printer is not appearing in InstalledPrinters

Tags: c#, printing

I'm trying to print some text via USB printer but it is not appearing in the list of installed printers [Printer details](http://posiflex.com.ua/images/sampledata/podderjka/manual/AURA-5200E.pdf) are here. Tried many solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6911828/3117296) but couldn't succeeded.

```
foreach (string printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    str_printers += printer+"\n";
}
```

Printer is also appearing in **other device** instead of **Printers** in windows 7 but a POS is printing 100% fine using this printer.
Any questions and answers are more than welcome

Comment: To print to thermal printer you have to use Pos.net library from Microsoft http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42081

Comment: Thanks @E-Bat. Currently I'm not on my Dev PC. I'll write back to you as soon as I tried. Thanks again.

Comment: @E-Bat getting the following exception while running the Sample project of OPOS.net `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {CCB90152-B81E-11D2-AB74-0040054C3719} failed due to the following error: 80040154`.