# Can I open a print a pdf document through c# with the print dialog

Tags: c#, printing

I have a PDF file I want to print through my program by bringing up the print dialog. Is there a way to do this without using external programs such as Adobe Reader?

Thanks, 
Richard

EDIT: For the time being I'm using Adobe as the most common place 3rd party program available that is also free. I'd still like to find other solutions though.

EDIT: Anyone down voting could you please explain why - it helps learning.

Comment: There are dozens of questions on Stack Overflow about PDF libraries for .NET applications. Did you try any of those? Do they not provide printing functionality?

Comment: @Cody not yet, I only wanted to provide similar functionality to the 'print' command which is built into windows command prompt so didn't think a 3rd party library would be needed.

Comment: Hmm, well you can show the Print dialog easily if that's all you want. But that dialog doesn't do anything by itself, it just provides a common way of obtaining printing preferences from the user. Once they "OK" the dialog, you'll have to actually do the printing yourself from your application (using a PDF reader library), or call the user's installed PDF reader (like Adobe Acrobat) to do the printing.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/273729/138071

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/pdfrasterizer.aspx I found this link that also can help you. Also your can search for a library to convert pdf to html and then print it

Comment: Have you tried Aspose.Pdf for .NET? Please see the [PDF printing related topics](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/working-with-printing.html) in the documentation. Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a 3rd party library like the PDF Component from Aspose.  There isn't anything natively in .NET that could do this.