# Print a PDF server side from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I need to take a PDF file url, send it as a parameter to a web service that will print it on a network printer. It has to be done server side without any user interaction.

Do you know some libraries that we can use to acheive that ? We look at different options like iTextSharp but it looks like there's no way to print from that library.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to generate the PDF on the server or are you printing an already existing PDF existing at the passed location?

Comment: We receive a pdf file from another system but we sometime need to open the file to do some resizing or margin ajustment. So both scenarios must be addressed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a PDF with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579624/how-to-print-a-pdf-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll finally use a commercial component that does all this by itself.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you can download the file and save it as a PDF and have Acrobat Reader installed you can use a command line to print it (shell it).

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/commandlineswitches.php#Acrobat

Print a PDF file silently:

```
AcroRd32.exe /N /T PdfFile PrinterName [ PrinterDriver [ PrinterPort ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to know what commercial component you used...

Comment: Pdf Rasterizer by TallComponent

Answer (score 0):

I had to something like that, but using PCL. We used winspool.drv to open the printer, start a document then a page, write out the bytes, then end the page & document and close the printer. We installed PCL drivers for the printer on the local machine to print to a network printer. 
You might be able to do something like that with Postscript drivers. A quick test would be to to a binary copy of a PDF to the printer using the command prompt and the /B switch on copy. I think you specify the PDF and the printers network share as source/destination. Use a small PDF to avoid getting a ream of random characters in case it doesn't work.

Comment: This will only work if the printer supports the PDF format natively, which is not very common.