# How to print a pdf in C# by using

Tags: c#, printing, process, system.printing, system.management

I used 'process' to print pdf file in C# app.But i cannot get the print status.I found that it is possible to interact with printer/queue with System.management and System.printing.I did a lot of trial n error using these two namespaces but couldnt print a file.Any examples availble on how to use these to print a pdf doc to printer?

Answer (score 3):

System.Printing cannot be used to print PDFs. PDFs has to be rendered to a printable file first.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579624/how-to-print-a-pdf-with-c-sharp/19320055#19320055) and its answers for a nice overview of different approaches.

If you're on linux you can easily call `lp` command.

Comment: Some details on PDF rendering:
https://www.debenu.com/blog/whats-difference-pdf-rendering-pdf-viewing-2.html

Answer (score 0):

This Question has already been answered here [How can I send a file document to the printer and have it print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103705/how-can-i-send-a-file-document-to-the-printer-and-have-it-print).

You cannot print a pdf with standard methods cause it needs to be rendered first, you can user Ghostscript, Adobe Acrobat or something else for that.

Edit: Johan was faster

Comment: But these examples doesnt show how to get status of print ..They Use Process to print file.From those process is it possible get print status? I guess no!!

Comment: @mmu not direct, no. But take a look at PrintServer.GetPrintQueues. This is can give you a printers status. Yo can check it in a second Thread or something. Im not sure if you look for the printers status or the print job status. If you want the print job status take a look at Win32_PrintJob.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `WPF` application, then use `System.Printing`.

Here's code:

```
var file = File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFilePath);
var printQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();

using (var job = printQueue.AddJob())
using (var stream = job.JobStream)
{
    stream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
}
```

Now, this namespace must be used with a `WPF` application.  It does not play well with `ASP.NET` or `Windows Service`.  It should not be used with `Windows Forms`, as it has `System.Drawing.Printing`.  I don't have a single issue with my PDF printing using the above code, but I'm all ears as to why it doesn't work for someone else.

I should mention that you have to have a printer that will support direct printing, as you're sending the information directly to the printer.  In my experience, this has worked with Brother HL series and Sharp enterprise printers.  I wish this would work for other things, such as Excel documents, but it doesn't.  Luckily, those are easy to print in other manners.

Comment: It would be nice if whoever gave this a downvote would provide feedback that lead them to their decision.  This has worked perfectly for me, but I'm all ears.  There might have been a specific case and it would be nice if you shared with others.

Comment: @KJ I did mention that you need to have a printer which supports direct printing... that's the last paragraph.