# ASCII CODE for Dot Matrix Printer for changing Ribbon in C# using Raw Printing

Tags: c#, ascii, dot-matrix

I am printing receipts using Dot Matrix Printer in C#.

The printer works perfectly, prints characters in bold, large size etc.

The problem is dot matrix have ribbons in it (Black color, Red Color)

How can i specify which text is to be printed in black or red.

I am using BinaryWriter to pass string and ascii code to get desired output.

Example:

```
 bw.Write((byte)0);

 byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

 foreach (var by in bytes)
 {
    bw.Write((byte)by);

 }
```

Some Sample Code Reference:

[Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402821/rawprinterhelper-not-printing-and-not-raising-error)

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

The printer used is Sewoo SLK-D30
[Sewoo SLK-D30](http://www.miniprinter.com/eng/product/list.php?cat=10)

The document says:

```
   Command  HexCode    Description

   DC3      <13>H      Red color print command
```

But not able to proceed.

Comment: This depends entirely on the protocol or printing control language (PCL) used by your model of printer. Refer to your printer's documentation.

Comment: There's nothing anyone can say here on StackOverflow without you stating which model of printer you're using and what protocol or PCL you're communicating to it with.

Comment: @Dai hi i had updated my question, can you please suggest something